# how to debug a stub class deployed in a jar file?

Tags: java, debugging, session, stub

I ask for some help here for debugging a class in a deployed jar file,
As the codes below, I have a stateless session bean and its interface packaged into a iiop.jar file which deployed to server, and I try to debug to see execution of testException method, but that class that read from a deployed jar file,

```
 StatelessSessionHome home = 
     (StatelessSessionHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
                getInitialContext().lookup(StatelessSessionHome.JNDI_NAME),
                StatelessSessionHome.class);
  StatelessSession session = home.create();
```

(break point here)      session.testException(-2);

the debug process will jump to the next step and ignore things happened in testException() with a follow message:
_StatelessSession_Stub.testException(int) line: not available
and asking to edit source path

Any suggestion should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging line by line, you often land on a class which is not a part of your source code (it could be inside a jar). In such cases it will show a message that the source is not available. If you are using eclipse, keep pressing F6 until you jump out of the library class back into your code so that you can continue debugging from that point.

Comment: I do have the source code for the generated iiop.jar, just when I deployed this iiop.jar to server, it try to use as a _StatelessSession_Stub, which I don't know how to debug with, and I tried to add break point to my statelesssessionbean source, and nothing happened during debug, break point did not stop server and test running.